# WHERE CLAUSE, condition that contain space in Where clause return no result the majority of time

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, where-clause

I'm using PHPMyAdmin 4.9.2 and when I'm using the clause WHERE(condition) with space in condition or dot the majority of the time that returns no result.

I'll give you an example:
I have this table

[image]

and when I type

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE CustomerName = 'Alfreds Futterkiste'
```

That work (return me the correct row) but when I type:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE Address = 'Obere Str. 57'
```

that return nothing.
basically when a make a request with the WERE CLAUSE that has a condition with space or with dot sometimes it returns noting but when it's a single word or a string with any space it returns me the row that I've asked.
I've tried that on a different table with a lot more rows and the request seems to work randomly, sometimes it works sometimes not.
I even reinstall WAMP and that's still not work

Thank you in advance for helping me because it blocks me in my learning because there are requests that I can't make because of it

Comment: It's probably just about your data: the `adress` might contain characters that you don't see, such as leading or trailing spaces, or else, and that generate a mismatch in the equality condition.

Comment: Ok thanks. but what can I do with that how do I resolve this because I create new table a lot of time and put data by hands

Comment: You can use something like `WHERE address LIKE 'Obere%Str%57'`

Comment: yea i already try that that working but i wanted too know why that doesn't work for me and for other that work.

Comment: Provide HEX(address) for a failing case.

Comment: ^^ no my table is real  you can make query like SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE CustomerName = 'Alfreds Futterkiste'
 and that work lol

Comment: GMB you were right it's trailing spaces thanks now that's working

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend renaming your fields to be a bit more consistent and less redundant ie. fields not containing 'customer' when they are already part of the 'Customer' table.

Second, try searching within the table rather than searching through fields alone. I recreated your table and executed some SQL to attempt to retrieve the same row. Here's what worked for me:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer
WHERE Customer.Address = 'Obere Str. 57'
```

Comment: i use the exacts same query with a "s" at the end of Customers and that return me nothing thank for your help tho

Comment: I'm using MariaDB is it why that doesn't work? I tried myself too

Comment: possibly, I tested mine on 'DB Browser' however both are executing SQL commands. Maybe try

WHERE Customer.Address == "Obere Str. 57"

Adding double quotes and the extra equals sign as typically found when querying for equality in other programming languages could be a difference maker here

Comment: Nah that's not working sorry i have learn sql a bit at school and it was working I don't know If i misconfigured  something when i install wamp i don't know i try with MYSQL AND mariadb

Comment: is it necessary to use mariadb?

Comment: look up DB Browser. its a lightweight tool to manage databases and execute sqlite queries

Comment: Ok I'll look that